# Redirecting ".local" subdomain to unicast DNS

Tags: dns, bonjour, zeroconf, mdns

I regularly access Windows domains that have been set up to use a domain under the `.local` top level name. This conflicts with Bonjour/Zeroconf which reserves `.local` for it's own use. A number of platforms support Bonjour out of the box (including Mac OS, iPhone, and Ubuntu) and there's numerous name resolution issues when this confict occurs.

I have a manual (per workstation) workaround in place for Mac OS by creating an `/etc/resolver/ntdomain.local` as per [`resolver(5)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20081010191427/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/resolver.5.html) which works well. Unfortunately this requires manual changes on every workstation and does not work on the iPhone.

What I'm looking for is a way to redirect requests for `*.ntdomain.local` coming in via mDNS to a specific unicast DNS server. I don't mind writing some code if required. I can deploy on either preferably Debian or alternatively Windows 2003. It looks like [Avahi](http://avahi.org/) may be the library I'm looking for.

Can this be done without registering every address in the subdomain or is it possible to register a single NS record of `ntdomain.local` that points to the Windows DNS server?

Comment: From my searches, `resolver(5)`, on current Apple online doc, can now only be found on https://opensource.apple.com/source/libresolv/libresolv-65/resolver.5.auto.html

Answer (score 4):

You can "merge" the unicast and multicast `.local` namespaces (with unicast taking precedence) as explained on [Avahi and Unicast .local](https://web.archive.org/web/20080705033435/http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal). Apple has [instructions for doing the same on Mac OS X](https://web.archive.org/web/20080514165559/http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=107800).

Another option is to add `domain-name=.localnet` to `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` to have it use `.localnet` instead of `.local` for the multicast DNS namespace.